# Git not showing 'assets' folder

Tags: android, git, netbeans

I have a folder called 'assets' ( auto generated when creating a new android app using the wizard in netbeans ) but it does not show up in the git command line, nor does it get added to the repo even if I try to.

Any help?

Comment: Have you checked it's not being ignored by a rule in a `.gitignore` file?

Comment: @imrad if the answer did help you, can you select it as the correct answer? Thx

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the directory is git-ignored. Check .gitignore at the root of your Git repo, and ~/.gitignore (your global ignore settings). Does assets show up in there? If so, do `git add -f assets/` to force the add.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't work with (empty) folders, only with files. If you need to commit a folder you need to check a file within, in order to force git to recreate that folder.

I suggest you to commit an empty file that begins with an underscore '.' like **".keep"**, *this file will be ignored by android build process.*

I hope that helps you